# Can I open a Corel Draw file in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, conversion, file-conversion

I have a Corel Draw file, but I don't have Corel Draw software with me.

Is it possible to open this file in Photoshop or convert it to a PSD or other image format?

I searched on the internet but didn't find any free software or plug-in that would do this.

Answer (score 2):

[Use Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/index.php?lang=en)! It's a really powerful graphical tool and it's free

[image]

> **[Can I open/import *.cdr (Corel Draw Vector drawing file) files in
>   Inkscape?](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_open.2Fimport_.2A.cdr_.28Corel_Draw_Vector_drawing_file.29_files_in_Inkscape.3F)**
>
> You can use the UniConvertor for
>   converting CDR files and some other
>   formats to SVG. In Inkscape 0.46,
>   there's an input extension that will
>   allow you to open or import CDR files
>   directly from Inkscape if you have
>   UniConvertor installed on your system.
>
> If you can't run UniConvertor, you can
>   try this workaround:
>
> - Open the CDR file in Corel Draw. Save it as binary encoded CGM* file.
>     It will save only vector graphics. It
>     will not save bitmap graphics.
> - Open the CGM file in OpenOffice Impress. Copy to Open Office Draw and
>     insert original JPG or another bitmap
>     graphics. Save file as ODG And you can
>     continue in Open Office Draw program.)
> - Select all (CTRL+A)
> - Export as SVG.
> - Open SVG file in Inkscape and correct mistakes if they appear.
> - Note: OpenOffice will open only binary encoded CGM files in Impress.
>     If the CGM is encoded using clear-text
>     encoding, it will be opened in
>     OpenOfice Writer, thus rendering the
>     next steps invalid.

Comment: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_open.2Fimport_.2A.cdr_.28Corel_Draw_Vector_drawing_file.29_files_in_Inkscape.3F

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_convert_a_psd_file) software? [Here](http://www.google.com/search?q=psd+file+converter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) is the search that I used.

EDIT: Found the [.cdr file converter](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnview.html). Well, at least the program claims to work with those files. So try XnView. I did not work with that program, but I found on some forum that it can convert cdr files.

Here is another one, looks like an online tool: [www.filespazz.com](http://www.filespazz.com/)

Comment: its wrong search , my question is from Coral Draw to PSD not from PSD to coral Draw.